# Integration of $\sqrt{x\over1-x^3}$ dx

Tags: integration

The question is self-explanatory. Below is my attempt:

$$\int \left(\frac{x}{1-x^3}\right)^{1/2}=$$

let $$u=x^3 \\ 
\frac{du}{dx}=3x^2 \\
dx=\frac{1}{3x^2}du$$

substitute in integral:

$$∫\frac{x^{1/2}}{(1-u)^{1/2}}\frac{1}{3x^2}du=
\frac{1}{3}∫\frac{1}{(u-u^2)^{1/2}}du$$

...

Thanks, y'all

Answer (score 2):

Sub $x=u^2$.  Then the integral is

$$\underbrace{2 \int du \, \frac{u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^6}}}_{v=u^3}  = \frac23 \int \frac{dv}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$$

I assume you can handle it from here.

Comment: @anja.wlotrzewiszczykowycki: No.  Work it out.  $x=u^2 \implies dx = 2 u \, du$.

Comment: is there a way I can upload a picture of my working out? my final answer is (1/3)arcsin(2x^3-1)+c